Detecting specific classes of objects in image
I want to pre-process images before training a classifier on them by detecting "distractor objects" (present in almost all images, but unrelated to the classification task) and cropping the images to remove the distractors. Those are: plastic vials with labels on them, paper envelopes, plastic cards with text and images on them. However, the pretrained Object Detection models I've found were all trained on COCO 2017 dataset, which doesn't have many categories (https://github.com/amikelive/coco-labels/blob/master/coco-labels-2014_2017.txt).  Are there any object detection models available which are capable of detecting a wider range of object classes?
